# Conditional relationship within model

Tags: php, laravel

I have a model containing a `unit_id` column and a `type` column, 2 rows can have the same `unit_id` but different `type`s. I have a method in the model

```
public function unit()
{
  if ($this->type == 'controller') {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\FMS\Controller', 'unit_id', 'id');
  } else {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\FMS\Unit', 'unit_id', 'id');
  }
}
```

that is meant to conditionally return a relationship depending on if the `type` column equals controller or not, although the check does not work and it just returns the second relationship, even if the `type` is `controller`

I understand it is not possible to access `$this` within a model so is there any way else I could get around this?

Comment: Your code should work, you can access $this from within your class. Try to call dd($this->type); to see what the type is set to?

Comment: @mrhn It will only work if the model has already been loaded. If the OP is eager loading the results that it will always fallback to the else block.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$this` will be available in your relationship methods, however, if you're eager loading the `unit` relationship (not lazy eager loading)  `type` will be `null`. This is because the `type` attribute won't have been set when the relationship `query` is built.

The code you have should work if you loading the relationship after the initial class has been loaded.

If you're using [load()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-collections#method-load) on an Eloquent Collection then I believe it will use whichever `type` is on the first Model in the collection.

---

#### Solution

What you have lends itself pretty will to [Polymorphic relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships).

Change your `unit()` method to be:

```
public function unit()
{
    return $this->morphTo('unit', 'type', 'unit_id');
}
```

The default for Polymorphic relationships with Laravel is to have the fully qualified namespace of the class as the type but since the type in this case is just going to be either `controller` or `unit` you'll need to tell Laravel how to map those words to the relevant classes. To do this you can use [Relation::morphMap()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#custom-polymorphic-types).
In the `boot()` method of your `AppServiceProvider` (to be fair, it can be any service provider) add the following:

```
Relation::morphMap([
    'unit'       => 'App\Models\FMS\Unit',
    'controller' => 'App\Models\FMS\Controller',
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use `$this` on the model class and your relationship may work somehow.

But I suggest you to use [Polymorphic Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships) instead.

```php
/**
 * Get the unit.
 */
public function unit()
{
    return $this->morphTo(__FUNCTION__, 'type', 'unit_id');
}
```

The `type` column is used by Eloquent to determine which "type" of parent model to return when accessing the unit relation, it would be either `App\Models\FMS\Controller` or `App\Models\FMS\Unit`.

To use your own custom types, you have to register the `morphMap` in the boot function of your `AppServiceProvider`:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation;

Relation::morphMap([
    'controller' => 'App\Models\FMS\Controller',
    'unit' => 'App\Models\FMS\Unit',
]);
```

Comment: Show how he should do it? this is a little sparse answer imo.